# Error when passing pointer to array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Point {
    double x;
};

void test(struct Point **a, int len)
{
    int i;

    printf("a = %p\n", a);
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("%f\n", a[i]->x);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int len = 4;

    struct Point *P;

    P = malloc(len*sizeof(struct Point));

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        P[i].x = i;
        printf("%f\n", P[i].x);
    }
    printf("&P = %p\n", &P);
    test(&P, len);

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to pass an array of structs to a function (I want to pass a pointer to the array, not make a copy). When I try to use the array inside the function, I get an access violation. What is the correct way to do this? What am I doing wrong? `a == &P`, so it should work, right?

Comment: But `P` already *is* a pointer, it points to the first element of the allocated memory (the array). By passing the pointer, as is, you're not copying anything but the actual pointer.

Comment: `printf("%f\n", (*a)[i].x);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why's you want a `struct Point **`? You can rewrite the same as

```
void test(struct Point *a, int len)
{
   //some stuff
    printf("%f\n", a[i].x);

}
```

and call it like

```
 test(P, len);
```

This way, IMHO, the requirement

> *I want to pass a pointer to the array*

is also met<sup>#</sup>.

---

<sup>(#) NOTE: To be strict, here we pass the *pointer to the first element of the array*, however, the behaviour compares equal. Thanks to Mr. **@alk** for the comment.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, So just to make sure, no copy is made when in the function, and any changes I make to the array still persist after the function returns?

Comment: To nitpick: The way you show a pointer to an array's 1st element is passed. This is different from a pointer to an array, the latter would be `struct Point (*pa)[len]`.

Comment: @alk Very True sir. Can you suggest the appropriate wordings to modify my answer?

Comment: Although there is no benefit of using `struct point ** `, the only wrong in OP 's code is `a[i]->x`.

Comment: @haccks Right sir. IMHO, OP is much concerned about `not make a copy` part, rather than the data type itself. So, I just tried to put it in a simplified way. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Passing `&p` to function `test` means that you are passing a pointer to the first element of an array of *one element* of type `struct Point *`. Therefore, only `a[0]` is valid (and hence `a[0]->x`) and all other `a[i]` are out of bound access. This will invoke undefined behavior.

Change `a[i]->x` to `a[0][i].x` or `(*a)[i].x` in `test` function.

Using pointer to pointer in this case is not worthy. This would be of worth using if passed pointer is to be modified in the function and that modification is expected to seen in the caller.

Comment: or better `(*a)[i].x`

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg , Isn't it supposed to be what JoachimPileborg suggested in the above comment?

Comment: @CoolGuy if we have `struct Point **a` `(*a)` is dereference of a pointer `[i]` is reading the value from the address so basically also pointer dereference... this means after these two operations we get a type `struct Point` ergo: we cannot acces as we would get `struct Point *`...

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg , I think you are right. So, Joachim's comment is wrong as he dereferences the pointer thrice?

Comment: @CoolGuy; Yes. I think he was confused then like me.

Comment: @ haccks, And like me :). @JoachimPileborg , That's wrong. See the above comments.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg; I think now you will disagree on changing `a[i]->x` to `(*a)[i]->x`.

Comment: `a[i]` will be wrong anyway. So how about `(*a)[i].x`? :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg; Yeah. `(*a)[i].x` is fine anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The array should be passed using the parameter `struct Point *a`.  When you increment `a` the pointer will move by `sizeof(struct Point)`.

```
void test(const struct Point *a, int len)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers offer you better alternatives.But I'll put this here to help anyone (myself) understand why it is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I want to pass a pointer to the array,

Taking your requirement literally you do it like this:

```
void test(size_t len, struct Point (*a)[len])
{
  size_t i;

  printf("a = %p\n", (void *) a);

  for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    printf("%f\n", (*a)[i].x);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
size_t len = 4;
struct Point * p = malloc(len * sizeof *p);

for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    p[i].x = i;
    printf("%f\n", p[i].x);
}

printf("p = %p\n", (void *) p);
printf("&p = %p\n", (void *) &p);

test(len, &p);
```

You could also implement the same functionality (looping over the array's elements) by going the way proposed by *[Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh)*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30104180/694576). You then would pass a pointer to the array's 1<sup>st</sup> element then, but a pointer to the array itself.